# Checking for loop and if conditional, yet it doesn't print string

Tags: python, list

For this code, I predicted that it would result in 'Rachel likes the languages 'Python', 'Javascript', 'HTML/CSS'' and  'ye', I got the first part but not the second part. Doesn't the code check each item in people list, and if that person is equal to the key of the fav_lang dictionary, it will print 'ye'?

```
fav_lang = {
    'Rachel':['Python','Javascript','HTML/CSS'],

}
for name, language in fav_lang.items():
    print(name, 'likes the languages', str(language).replace('[','',1).replace(']',''))

people = ['Rachel','Hannah','Safia','Ilda']
for peeps in people:
    if peeps == fav_lang.keys():
        print('ye')
```

gives the output:

```
Rachel likes the languages 'Python', 'Javascript', 'HTML/CSS'
```

Comment: change `if peeps == fav_lang.keys():` to `if peeps in fav_lang:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following part:

```
for peeps in people:
    if peeps == fav_lang.keys():
        print('ye')
```

To:

```
for peeps in people:
    if peeps in fav_lang.keys():
        print('ye')
```

Because `fav_lang.keys()` returns a list.